# Extending views in spring 4

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, taglib

I want to create view file that extends some layout.jsp. To do that I used JSTL and tags folder, my layout from `/WEB-INF/tags/` looks like this:

```
<%@tag description="Main layout" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@attribute name="head" fragment="true" %>
<%@attribute name="footer" fragment="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <jsp:include page="../partials/defaultHead.jsp">
        <jsp:invoke fragment="head"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <jsp:include page="../partials/header.jsp">
        </header>
        <main>
            <jsp:doBody>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <jsp:include page="../partials/footer.jsp">
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my view:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<t:main>
    This is the content of this website.
</t:main>
```

I have JSTL and taglibs-c libraries installed (maven, pom.xml). And my problem is that I keep getting the following error:

```
No tag "main" defined in tag library imported with prefix "t"
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Forgot to mention - the layout file is indeed named `main.jsp`, so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned in your comment

> Forgot to mention - the layout file is indeed named **main.jsp**, so it
>   should work

It won't work. change the file name to **main.tag**